# How do you execute one of two methods continuously when they run indefinitely and one based off a keypress event?

Tags: java, android, methods, actionlistener, timing

I am making an application that depends on a user pressing a key and time based events. The methods will run under two circumstances:

**1:** If the user presses a key the application prints foo.

**2:** If 3 seconds elapse then the application prints bar.

The first scenario runs independently of the the second, but the second is dependent on the first. The 3 second timer should  reset every time the `keypress event` is called. After one of these two methods execute the application should return to a state where the application is waiting for one of the these two events to occur again.

Code might look similar to the following

```
@override
public void onPress(int i){
    System.out.print("foo");
}

public void printBar(){
    if(timeElapsed > 3){
        System.out.print("bar");
    }
}
```

So the on press event should occur normally when the key is pressed, but printBar should only run 3 seconds after the most recent execution of the most recent keyPress. Every execution of keypress should reset the printBar timer. Thank you for your help and let me know if I can provide better information.

Comment: Multithreading with a lock.

Comment: You tag this question with [tag:android], but you are listening for key press events. This makes no sense to me. Android phones don't have keys, right?

Comment: I am creating my own Keyboard, so the key refers to a keyboard key. I didn't include that keyboard in the description because I thought the generalized question still achieved what I was asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me give you a general idea of how to do this.

I assume that your keypress method works correctly (always prints foo when the key is pressed). What you need to resolve now, is how to reset the timer.

I don't know what kind of timer you are using. But I guess because the app has something to do with key press events, and possibly you are using swing. I would recommend you to use `java.swing.Timer`.

It is very easy to get how much time has elapsed using a swing timer.

```
final Timer t = new Timer (3000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }
});
```

This is very simple. 3000 means 3000 milliseconds or 3 seconds. When s seconds is elapsed, `actionPerformed` gets executed. In `actionPerformed`, you can just call your `printBar` (without the check!) or you can call `System.out.println` to meet the requirement.

So now we have this set up, how are we going to reset it?

Luckily, the `Timer` class provides a very helpful method, called `restart`. In your `onPress` method, just call this method

```
@Override
public void onPress () {
    System.out.println("foo");
    t.restart();
}
```

BOOM! You've done it!

Comment: Thanks. That helped out a lot and pointed me in the right direction to use it in more ways than I planned.